# 'run' phase is ready to proceed to the 'extract' phase

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I am trying to run a couple of test cases using script.But I am getting an error message after running the first test case.This stops the simulation.I am attaching the LOG with this mail.I don't understand why this is happening.

I checked previous posts and added +UVM_OBJECTION_TRACE in the vsim command.But I am not able to find out the cause of the error.Can anybody help me??

```
# UVM_INFO @ 0: run [OBJTN_TRC] Object uvm_test_top raised 1 objection(s): count=1  total=1
# UVM_INFO @ 0: run [OBJTN_TRC] Object uvm_top added 1 objection(s) to its total (raised from source object uvm_test_top): count=0  total=1
# AT TIME=0,APB MASTER IN RESET MODE
# AT TIME=1200000,APB MASTER IN ACTIVE MODE
# AT TIME=45400000,*************************** EXPECTED_DATA=1792474624,RECEIVED DATA=1792474624
# AT TIME=186600000,*************************** EXPECTED_DATA=222,RECEIVED DATA=222
# AT TIME=231800000,*************************** EXPECTED_DATA=1504340502,RECEIVED DATA=1504340502
# AT TIME=349000000,*************************** EXPECTED_DATA=2367782205,RECEIVED DATA=2367782205
# UVM_INFO Test_Cases/my_test.sv(40) @ 349000000: uvm_test_top [root objections] 
# The total objection count is 1
# ---------------------------------------------------------
# Source  Total   
# Count   Count   Object
# ---------------------------------------------------------
# 0       1       uvm_top
# 1       1         uvm_test_top
# ---------------------------------------------------------
# 
# UVM_INFO Test_Cases/my_test.sv(43) @ 349000000: uvm_test_top [my_component objections] 
# The total objection count is 1
# ---------------------------------------------------------
# Source  Total   
# Count   Count   Object
# ---------------------------------------------------------
# 1       1         uvm_test_top
# ---------------------------------------------------------
# 
# UVM_INFO @ 349000000: run [OBJTN_TRC] Object uvm_test_top dropped 1 objection(s): count=0  total=0
# UVM_INFO @ 349000000: run [OBJTN_TRC] Object uvm_test_top all_dropped 1 objection(s): count=0  total=0
# UVM_INFO @ 349000000: run [OBJTN_TRC] Object uvm_top subtracted 1 objection(s) from its total (dropped from source object uvm_test_top): count=0  total=0
# UVM_INFO @ 349000000: run [OBJTN_TRC] Object uvm_top subtracted 1 objection(s) from its total (all_dropped from source object uvm_test_top): count=0  total=0
# UVM_INFO verilog_src/uvm-1.1d/src/base/uvm_objection.svh(1268) @ 349000000: reporter [TEST_DONE] 'run' phase is ready to proceed to the 'extract' phase
# 
# --- UVM Report Summary ---
# 
# ** Report counts by severity
# UVM_INFO :   12
# UVM_WARNING :    0
# UVM_ERROR :    0
# UVM_FATAL :    0
# ** Report counts by id
# [OBJTN_TRC]     6
# [Questa UVM]     2
# [RNTST]     1
# [TEST_DONE]     1
# [my_component objections]     1
# [root objections]     1
# ** Note: $finish    : C:/questasim_10.2c/win32/../verilog_src/uvm-1.1d/src/base/uvm_root.svh(430)
#    Time: 349 us  Iteration: 68  Instance: /my_top
# 1
# Break in Task uvm_pkg/uvm_root::run_test at C:/questasim_10.2c/win32/../verilog_src/uvm-1.1d/src/base/uvm_root.svh line 430
# Simulation Breakpoint: 1
# Break in Task uvm_pkg/uvm_root::run_test at C:/questasim_10.2c/win32/../verilog_src/uvm-1.1d/src/base/uvm_root.svh line 430
# MACRO ./run_do PAUSED at line 18
```

Comment on this question

Comment: I don't see any errors in this log file.  I see a test that runs and finishes.  What is the error? Going from the run phase to the extract phase seems like the normal think to do when the test finishes.

Comment: That's ok.. But it is not proceeding to the next test case automatically.
I have to hit the RUN button manually. Then it takes the next test case. After that it stops again.
Even adding a run command in the do file is not working.

Comment: Sounds like the problem is in your run script.  You should post that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about what script your are talking about. But it looks like you do not quit vsim. Try `quit` in your do file.